# How to record iphone screen via terminal

Tags: ios, iphone, screen-recording

I want to record my iphone screen when running monkey tests to see later on that what it is doing.

Is there any command that we can use to start recording.

Comment: I know you can record via Quicktime. But don't know of a terminal command...

Comment: @rockythere are tutorials that how to record via Quicktime/UI...no actual tutorial that shows how to record via a command line.... like android where you can simply record a screen with a command.